# How to convert getColorStateList (JAVA->C# xamarin for android)

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

this is java code-:

```
mText.setTextColor(getResources().getColorStateList(R.color.xml_color_selector))
```

i tried convert to C#(this code in getView)

```
mText.SetTextColor(parent.Context.Resources.GetColorStateList(Resource.Drawable.xml_color_selector));;
```

Unhandled Exception:

> Android.Content.Res.Resources+NotFoundException: File res/drawable/xml_color_selector.xml from color state list resource ID #0x7f0200a3

**how to convert to C# code?**

ps. xml_color_selector.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

  <item android:state_activated="true" android:drawable="@color/menu_item_background_color_pressed" />
  <!-- Pressed tab -->
  <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/menu_item_background_color_pressed" />
  <!-- Non Pressed tab -->
  <item android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />

</selector>
```

Comment: I'm guessing `.Resources+NotFoundException: File res/drawable/xml_color_selector.xml ` is a big clue

Comment: @user1 NotFound the GetColorStateList..?

Comment: found.  ListItemText.SetTextColor(Context.Resources.GetColorStateList(Resource.Color.menu_item_title_color_selector_activated)); and android:drawable -> android:color